# How to make YouTube (and any video) work with my proxy?

Tags: video, youtube, proxy

I have a HTTP proxy set in my wifi settings. It works with all HTTP requests, except any video.

But it works with my computer and the exact same HTTP proxy setting.

So, yeah, it really bother me (since 3 years), but today I would like to solve it!

More info: I have a Nexus 4 under 4.2.2 and rooted and I'm a proficient programmer and linux user.